Call of Power information function
I have simple script file, which works fine if I run as Administrator:
powercfg /SLEEPSTUDY /XML

Which saves the file C:\Windows\System32\sleepstudy-report.xml.
But when I try call the script from the C++ program, I receive an error
message:

The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded.

The process is running as Administrator
I tried to use different ways to Create the process system, ShellExecuteA, and more energy.dll in same dictionary.
How am I supposed to get a log of the Power States of the computer, at least for the last hour? Event Viewer doesn't work for Sleep/Resume Events, at least on Windows 11.

Added the widnows tag as the question seems windows specific.

Why call a script from C++ when you can use the Windows API directly? Windows API power managment functions

You are running the 32-bit version of powercfg.exe. Run the 64-bit version instead.

@PepijnKramer Because the Windows API doesn't generate nice XML reports.
